# Long Running App Engine Script "Quitting on terminated signal"

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, timeout

I am attempting to run several long running scripts via app engine. I am a beginner and this is the first project where I have used App Engine and express.

I am handling requests in Node using express.

When I (or a cron job) sends a request to any of my endpoints the script seems to run fine until a random point  ~5-10 mins later where I get the following logs:

1. The Project receives a "/_ah/stop" request
2. "Quitting on terminated signal" message
3. "Start program failed: user application failed with exit code -1 (refer to stdout/stderr logs for more detail): signal: terminated"

I cannot work out why this is happening.

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs10
instance_class: B2
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 25
  idle_timeout: 12m
```

Request handler code:

```
app.get("/longRunningFunctionOne", async (req, res) => {
    await longRunningFunctionOne();
    res.send("DONE");
});

app.get("/longRunningFunctionTwo", async (req, res) => {
    await longRunningFunctionTwo();
    res.send("DONE");
});

app.get("/_ah/start", async (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Absolutely no issues when running locally. Any idea what I am doing to get the premature /_ah/stop request? Because I am using basic scaling I wouldn't get a timeout. Which is described by google as being:

"24 hours for HTTP requests and task queue tasks. If your app doesn't return a request within this time limit, App Engine interrupts the request handler and emits an error for your code to handle."

Any ideas? Perhaps something to do with how I handle /_ah/start which was just a shot in the dark?

Comment: How do you call your endpoint? Did you already deploy with automatic scaling before?

Comment: I have tried calling it in my browser or through cron. Neither work. Inititally it was deployed with automatic scaling but I have now changed it to basic with the app.yaml you can see above. Could it be that because the /_ah/start handler returns a response immidiately, the 24 hour request timeout won't apply to my function endpoints and the instance closes after the 12m idle timeout?

Comment: I have checked to see if memory usage was the issue and can rule that out.

Comment: No, the start endpoint should not be a problem. Are you sure that all the instances of the previous version are stopped?

Comment: I have periodically deleted previous versions so fairly certain that isn't the case. The time between the  /_ah/start and  /_ah/stop requests is consistantly 12 mins which is what makes me think that it is an issue with the idle timeout (set to "idle_timeout: 12m" in my app.yaml).

Comment: Possible... I never experienced this. In production our applications have 600m as timeout. Have a try and let me know. Still interesting to learn from your experience!

Comment: Are your idle_timeouts 600m? I tried setting this and get the following error: idle_timeout (36000.0) must be in the range [10.0, 3600.0]

Comment: No, sorry, I checked is `idle_timeout: 600s`. So, it shouldn't be your issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that because I send very infrequent requests to the app I was hitting the instance idle timeout before my script had finished/

So even though a task was still running on the app, because it hadn't received a http request in the last ~15 mins, it would send the /_ah/stop request and shutdown the instance.

To keep the instance alive whilst the script is running, I created a function which sends the app a request every min to keep it up and not hit the idle timeout.

I call it the Beegees "stayin' alive" function:

```
const appUrl = "https://myurl.appspot.com/";

app.get("/script1", async (req, res) => {
    res.send("running script 1");
    stayAlive(script1);
});

app.get("/script2", async (req, res) => {
    res.send("running script 2");
    stayAlive(script2);
});

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    res.send(" ");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT || 4000}`);
});

const stayAlive = async (mainAsyncFunc) => {
  const intervalId = setInterval(sendAppRequest, 60000);
  await mainAsyncFunc();
  clearInterval(intervalId);
};

const sendAppRequest = () => {
  console.log("Stayin alive");
  axios.get(appUrl);
};
```

Seems kinda weird but it works. If you know a better way then please let me know.

Comment: I also faced a similar "issue" and ended up having a scheduled run to call one of the keepalive endpoint every 5 mins. Wish there was a better way to say GAE to not kill the app

Comment: I like what you figured out, any update on an actual solution?

Comment: Yeah I am facing the same issue @Dan Williams. Can you please help out?

Comment: Depending the situation, you might consider using Cloud Tasks. https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs

Comment: Doesn't work for me...

Comment: I found out with logging that mine clears the interval before it sends App requests